# Why doesn't this code remove newline characters from text copied to the clipboard?

Tags: python, pdf, pyperclip

I often copy text from PDFs into my notes and doing so almost always creates formatting issues.  So to start, I'm just trying to create a simple script to remove newline characters from text copied to my clipboard.

Here's a [LINK](https://brianlangis.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/seth-klarman-the-value-of-not-being-sure.pdf) to the pdf I'm currently using.

I've tried this:

```
import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()
new_text = text.strip()
pyperclip.copy(new_text)
```

I've also tried this:

```
import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()
new_text = text.replace('\n', "")
pyperclip.copy(new_text)
```

I've read all of the related questions and answers on this subject but can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also removing "\r". Some modules/programs don't adress the different types of line breaks in windows and other OSs

Comment: This did the trick. I had tried that as well but my original code removing "\r" was using 'text' instead of "new_text". Thanks!